# how to validate form when click eWAY paynow button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, payment-gateway

i have create eway paynow button within form.

```
    <form action="?" method="POST">
  Name: <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="" />

  <script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"
   class="eway-paynow-button" 
  data-publicapikey="epk-6AEE4269-0010-4415-A327-8064928AEFD0"
  data-amount="0"
  data-currency="AUD" 
  data-allowedit="true"
  data-resulturl="http://example.com/responseMsg.php">
</script>

</form>
```

i need to check whether  customer_name field empty or not before load eway payment
form. if customer_name field empty don't load eway payment form.how do i do this??can i run javascript to validate this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pay Now button doesn't provide a hook to run a function before opening the payment form, nor does it use event listeners at the moment. The solution here is to:

1. Capture the original onclick handler
2. Add a new event listener which performs validation, then calls the original onclick if successful.

I've stuck to pure JS for this, jQuery would allow a cleaner implementation :-)

Also note I've removed the `data-resulturl` attribute and moved the URL to form tag, otherwise the window may just redirect without submitting.

```
<form action="http://example.com/responseMsg.php" method="POST">
  Name: <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="" />

  <script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"
   class="eway-paynow-button" 
  data-publicapikey="epk-6AEE4269-0010-4415-A327-8064928AEFD0"
  data-amount="10"
  data-currency="AUD" 
  data-allowedit="true"
  data-submitform="yes">
</script>

</form>

<script>

  window.onload = function() {
    // Find the eWAY Pay Now button - note getElementsByClassName is IE9+
    var ewayButton = document.getElementsByClassName("eway-button")[0];

    // save and remove old onclick
    var oldeWAYclick = ewayButton.onclick;
    ewayButton.onclick = null;

    // Add new listener with validation
    ewayButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
        // Stop form from submitting itself
        e.preventDefault();

        // Example validation
        var name = document.forms[0]["customer_name"].value;
        if (name == null || name == "") {
            alert("Please complete all fields");
            return;
        }   
        // Display payment form
        oldeWAYclick();
    }, false);
  };

</script>
```